# Partition of integer with size constraint

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

A rather straightforward combinatorial question:

Given numbers $X, q, n$ such that $0 \leq X \leq n(q-1)$, what are the total number of ways to express $X$ as sum of $n$ numbers, where each summand is between $0$ and $q-1$ and the order does matter (e.g. $1+2$ and $2+1$ are considered different)?

I'd assume that there is an established formula for this but I couldn't find it via Google. If someone can give me a pointer to the result it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You might try starting with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)). Order doesn't matter there plus there is not extra limit to the numbers you can use like you have but it is a starting point.

Comment: There usually are no such partitions. Just take $q=2$, $n=2$ and $X=2^n$.

Comment: You might find this helpful: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)

Comment: Olivier: my bad; n(q-1) is what I meant.

Comment: Newb: exactly what I needed; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can form a recurrence.  Add $1$ to all the summands to get rid of the zeros.  Now we want the number of compositions of $X+n$ into $n$ parts of maximum size $q$.  Let $N(X+n,n)$ be the desired number of compositions of $X+n$ into $n$ parts of size at most $q$.  Then $$N(i,n)=\begin {cases} 0 & i \lt n\\ 1& i=n\\ \sum_{j=1}^q N(i-j,n-1) & i \gt n\end {cases} $$

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I was looking for the closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out "Composition" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) is the name of the concept I was looking for. Thanks to Newb for pointing it out to me.